# ThreeJS : objects don't cast shadow on others

Tags: three.js, shadow

I'm using `three v0.85.2`.

By default, all my objects are configured to cast and receive shadows :

```
const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material)

mesh.castShadow = meshConfig.castShadow
mesh.receiveShadow = meshConfig.receiveShadow
```

`shadowMap` of the `renderer` is enabled.

Self shadows seem to be correctly rendered (green squares in the image below).
But shadows casted to other objects are missing (red squares).

[image]

The problem seems to occur with all my meshes.
I don't find a way to make them appear.

Comment: if you use `THREE.DirectionalLight()`, then read [this](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow). Also, you can try to play around with `.left`, `.top`, `.right` and `.bottom` properties of `light.shadow.camera`

Comment: @prisoner849 : This works perfectly. You can post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome ) Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DirectionalLightShadow](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow), there you can read how to work with shadows when you use `THREE.DirectionalLight()` in your scene.

Also you can play around with `.left`, `.top`, `.right` and `.bottom` properties of the shadow camera of your light source.

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,1);
light.position.set(50, 500, 22);
light.target.position.set(300, 400, 200);

light.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;       
light.shadow.camera.far = 5000;      
light.shadow.camera.left = -500;
light.shadow.camera.bottom = -500;
light.shadow.camera.right = 500;
light.shadow.camera.top = 500;

light.castShadow = true;
scene.add(light);
```

three.js r85

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/z5xk8016/) example